# Make numeric Textbox Like (###,###,###)

Tags: c#, winforms, string-formatting

I have a numeric textbox that separate numbers like this (###,###,###) and use this code:

```
private void txtnum2_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
     if (!char.IsControl(e.KeyChar)
        && !char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar)
        && e.KeyChar != '.')
    {
        e.Handled = true;
        txtnum2.Text += Convert.ToString(e.KeyChar);
    }

    if (e.KeyChar == '.'
        && (sender as TextBox).Text.IndexOf('.') > -1)
    {
        e.Handled = true;
    }

    txtnum2.Text = Regex.Replace(txtnum2.Text, "[^.0-9]", "");


        for (int i = 1, j = 0; i < 10; ++i)
        {
            try
            {
                txtnum2.Text = txtnum2.Text.Insert(txtnum2.Text.Length - ((3 * i) + j), ",");
                ++j;
            }
            catch { }
        }
```

but after first "," other numbers go to the first of the textbox.

Comment: Are you using winforms? If so - have a look at `MaskedTextBox`: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.maskedtextbox(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Please consider upvoting and marking answer for those solutions that help or solve your problem.  Feel free to leave a comment if they dont quite get there.

Answer (score 0):

In Winforms (as @drew_w points out) you would use a [`MaskedTextBox`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.maskedtextbox%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
maskedTextBox1.Mask = "###,###,###";
maskedTextBox1.KeyDown += new KeyEventHandler(txtnum2_KeyPress);
```

In WPF, you might look to [this blog post](http://blindmeis.wordpress.com/2010/06/01/wpf-masked-textbox-behavior/) ([translation](http://www.google.com/translate?hl=en&sl=de&tl=en&u=http://blindmeis.wordpress.com/2010/06/01/wpf-masked-textbox-behavior/&sandbox=1))